# FuzzyDL doesn't work

Tags: fuzzy-logic

I am using FuzzyDL with Mac OS.

The exit status is always:

> 133 - no computation of the input (example files!).

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to import Gurobi library.